# How to declare several properties on one line

Tags: kotlin

I'm developing a class with several `lateinit` properties of one type. I think it's too verbose to declare each of them on separate line like this:

```
lateinit var a: String 
lateinit var b: String
```

so I would like to declare them on one line like this:

```
lateinit var b, c: String // error: Property getter or setter expected
```

But I get an error `Property getter or setter expected`. Is there any way to declare several properties on one line in Kotlin?

Comment: [Related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385878/define-multiple-variables-at-once-in-kotlin-e-g-java-string-x-y-z/40386049#40386049) that covers both variables and properties.

Comment: lateinit var b, c: String => this notation is wrong for programmatically syntax, lateinit var (b, c): String => if it can be, this would be better...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. Declaring multiple properties on the same line is frowned upon by many Java style guides, so we did not implement support for that in Kotlin.

Comment: Is there any chance it will be implemented later?

Comment: We have no such plans at this time.

Comment: Hmm maybe it's personal preference but I rather assign x,y,z in one line than having three new lines of code.

Comment: @yole why exactly is it frowned upon.? can you state any examples where it is considered bad and why. Considering that kotlin is all about eliminating boilerplate code, it would reduce redundant code if it was allowed in kotlin as well!

Comment: "Declaring multiple properties on the same line is frowned upon by many Java style guides" - citation needed. Since Java doesn't have "properties" in the same sense as Kotlin, it would be helpful to clarify what this means. Maybe you're referring to fields?

Comment: @yole in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40386049/2679529) I provided examples of declaring multiple variables and multiple properties in the same line. I'm using Kotlin version 1.1.2-5 (JRE 1.8.0_144-b01).

Comment: @yole Why don't you add this expression it would be fine for same class:  lateinit var (a, b, c): String

Comment: Not sure why you believed it is frowned upon. It's much cleaner and has been a common standard wherever I have worked.

Answer (score 10):

Looking at the grammar this is not possible:

```
property (used by memberDeclaration, declaration, toplevelObject)
  : modifiers ("val" | "var")
      typeParameters? (type "." | annotations)?
      (multipleVariableDeclarations | variableDeclarationEntry)
      typeConstraints
      ("by" | "=" expression SEMI?)?
      (getter? setter? | setter? getter?) SEMI?
  ;
```

You can only do destructing declarations with:

```
val (name, age) = person
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use kotlin's **destructuring declaration**, but it doesn't work for `lateinit` prefix.

```
var (a, b, c, d) = listOf("fly", 23, "slow", 28)
println("$a $b $c $d")
```

> It is a workaround and creates unnecessary list initialization but it gets the job done.

Also you won't be able to define variable types yourself but the type inference is automatically done when using destructuring declarations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize multiple fields with the same value, you can do something like this:

`val (x, y, z) = List(3) { 1 }`

`val (x, y, z) = List(3) { "Hello" }`

and so on.