# Define multiple variables at once in Kotlin (e.g Java : String x,y,z;)

Tags: variables, kotlin

I was wondering if there is any way to define multiple variables in Kotlin at once like in Java and almost every other existing language in the world .

like in Java :

```
String x = "Hello World!", y = null, z;
```

Comment: This seems to be a good example of a case where something that's really elegant in Java (declaring multiple variables, not properties) is verbose and awkward in Kotlin.

Comment: The question linked to as a duplicate is about *properties*. So it's not a duplicate of this question about *variables*. Voting to **reopen**. An answer stating that it's not possible to declare multiple properties on one line doesn't imply that it's not possible to declare multiple variables on one line.

Comment: @LarsH wow I myself didn't even think of that. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @LarsH Thanks for your comment. I've updated the accepted answer to clarify about both variables and properties.

Comment: Actually this is why Kotlin came to the surface to make the life of the programmer easier and avoid nulls in order to eliminate bugs as much as possible. So in that case `String x,y,z;` would not make any sense...

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can declare (and assign) multiple [**variables**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/declaring-variables.html) in one line by using semicolons (`;`):

```kotlin
val number = 42; val message = "Hello world!";
```

You can also declare (and assign) multiple [**properties**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) in the same line similarly:

```kotlin
class Example {
    var number = 42; var message = "Hello world!";
}
```

A runnable example illustrating both insights that you can [try online at tio.run](https://tio.run/##fVJPT8IwFL/vUzy5uClCQjyBmhhjomfjyRjz2B5Q7dql7VQ0fPb5WsrGDLpT2/f72/VNOylU0@QSrYXbTywrSfCdAH/jMRTEAyPUEspaOuFnldEVGSfIglCAYHnKx6xCgfWOBlRdzslM75WbhX1J1uKSpg/Oa82SnXyulXWmzp024FbooNSFWHhpt2InNFiSI8NbDVRWK7Tii8KMYQsypHKyQWxPKX3p7Ifw0vfOYjf/bWFwCZEAJzBph5Hmp3E5cvqx4uo3aCnNAnCTbJJkUSsoUagUzdJO4doYXF9s3a6yf6/SEBZnWsm1vySBc/n3ncou7flkFg66hIM7klLDhzayOBrMAmVnW7Gl865upS1L6pyprV1ABYhU6eDJ13getU4DOI222UHgXgJGxl3Wsxf8W5ADYMiACvT8lXLHq6KLJpzde1bHvl0ds/miTGGL@DbTbaBhz60LFlG/SrDC6HCRFt/v4gmtw6ZpfgA) (it also worked fine in my local environment using Kotlin version 1.1.2-5 (JRE 1.8.0_144-b01)):

```kotlin
class Example {
    // declaring multiple properties in a single line
    var number:Int; var message:String;

    // constructor that modifies the parameters to emphasize the differences
    constructor(_number:Int, _message:String) {
        number = _number * 2
        message = _message.toUpperCase()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // declaring multiple read-only variables in a single line
    val number = 42; val message = "Hello world!";
    
    // printing those local variables
    println("[main].number = " + number)
    println("[main].message = " + message)
    
    // instantiating an object and printing its properties' values
    val obj = Example(number,message)
    println("[Example].number = " + obj.number)
    println("[Example].message = " + obj.message)
}
```

Execution output:

```
[main].number = 42
[main].message = Hello world!
[Example].number = 84
[Example].message = HELLO WORLD!
```

As a contradictory side note, in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036345/how-to-declare-several-properties-on-one-line), JetBrains' Engineer [*yole*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147024/yole) states that:

> "Declaring multiple properties on the same line is frowned upon by
>   many Java style guides, so we did not implement support for that in
>   Kotlin."

Note that his answer is more than 4-years old, so there could have been changes since then.

Comment: Thank you , i couldn't find an answer on stackoverflow nor the kotlin website , however i tried their online converter for String x,y,z; and it gave them on three diffrenet lines , so i guessed it isn't possible

Comment: This is possible though `val (x, y) = arrayOf(20, "Hello")`

Comment: @RahulParashar  `Destructuring declarations are only allowed for local variables/values`, so my example does not work for properties.

Comment: The right way to do this is `val(x,y) = listOf(20,"Hello")`.  One can use this trick to declare any number of variables in Kotlin. The types are static and implicit by the type of the values inside list.

Comment: Complete example:
`function main() {
val (a,b,c,d) = listOf(21.8, "Hello", 231.3, "shark")
println("$a $b $c $d")`
}`

Comment: Even in Java, is declaring multiple variables in one line really bad practice? I think there are places where it reduces redundant code.

Comment: @VenkataRaju you should post it as an answer

Comment: @Shubh Since this question was marked duplicate, `Stack Overflow` does not allow any new answers.

Comment: That's pretty dumb. Kotlin is supposed to be concise, Java pretty much frowns upon anything concise...doesn't make a bit of sense.

Comment: You can use terminator for multiple variables inline `var first = "" ; var second = "" ; var third = "" `

Comment: `val(x,y) = listOf(20,"Hello")` Seems like allocating a list just to initialize multiple variables on one line is bad practice

Comment: The fact that Kotlin doesn't allow declaration of multiple *properties* on one line doesn't answer the question of whether declaration of multiple *variables* is allowed... unless someone supplies information showing that all variables in Kotlin are properties.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is much improved. +1

Comment: @Hasen Kotlin is not supposed to be concise only, it is also supposed to be readable.

Comment: @Hasen Kotlin is primarily *clear*, not *concise*. Often those goals align, but the Kotlin designers always choose what they consider to be clearest (and least-bug-prone) over what is most concise.

Answer (score 36):

Try this:

```
fun main() {
    val (x, y, z) = listOf(1, true, "Sam")    //can be "arrayOf(), "Pair()" or other types
    println("$x, $y, $z")
}
```

Output：

```
1, true, Sam
```

Comment: This is taking advantage of [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html).

Comment: Indeed, and if you have only two varablkes you can use a Pair for this:

`val (a, b) = "a" to "b"`

Answer (score 2):

You might also find "Destructuring declarations﻿" helpful here.

An example:

```
val (name, age) = person
```

More detail at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html.