# Property getter or setter expected in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am learning `Kotlin` from official docs, I am trying to create a class to do arithmetic operations.

```
class Sum {

    var a: Int, b: Int;

    constructor(a: Int, b: Int) {
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }

    fun add(): Int {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

I have this class, now I want to create an object of this class like

```
val sum = Sum(1,2)
Log.d("Sum", sum.add())
```

I am getting this error in `Sum` class:

> Property getter or setter expected

on `b: int;` within the line `var a: Int, b: Int;`

Comment: Read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are writing unnecessary code in your class.

Write short form for `constructor` if there is only one.

If there are properties in class, they can be defined in `constructor` by using `val` or `var`.

Use it like following:

```
class Sum (var a: Int,var b: Int){

    fun add(): Int {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

Do read [Basic Syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html) of `Kotlin`.

Answer (score 15):

```
var a: Int, b: Int;
```

Kotlin doesn't allow to have multiple declarations in one line. You have to go for:

```
var a: Int
var b: Int
```

instead. The Kotlin folks simply found the C/java practice of "int a, b, .." to be something they wish to **not** support in Kotlin.

Comment: variable must be initialised. this statement will have compile time error.

Comment: try putting your code in IDE you will know. It gives compile time error `Property must be initialised`.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.0 with latest kotlin 1.1.2-4, it gives above mentioned compile time error.

Comment: Your code isn't what I am talking about. Again: use the Sum class as the OP does. Because he as a ctor there that initializes those two fields! And sorry, that was misleading. Just having `Sum  { a b }` of course does not work. But having that with the ctor works fine!

Answer (score 6):

The error you have would be solved simply declaring the variables in two lines:

```
var a: Int
var b: Int
```

However, the recommended way to integrate those variables in constructors (if you only want to have a single constructor with arguments):

```
class Sum(var a: Int, var b: Int) {
    fun add(): Int = a + b
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly , you must put property declarations on separate lines . You can refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385878/define-multiple-variables-at-once-in-kotlin-e-g-java-string-x-y-z/40386049) here , where JetBrains' Engineer yole states that:

> Declaring multiple properties on the same line is frowned upon by many Java style guides, so we did not implement support for that in Kotlin.

Once property declaration on separate lines is done , you should have no problem as kotlin genrates default getter and setter internally with same visibility as your property . If you do not specify any visibility modifier, public is used by default, which means that your declarations will be visible everywhere .

In fact, Kotlin has a concise syntax,  for declaring properties and initializing them from the primary constructor(In case you have only one constructor which will be always primary):

```
  class Sum(var a:Int,var b:Int) {

    fun add(): Int {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

Refer constructors column in official documentation in link below https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

the following code shows you how to assign and manipulate variables in your class

```
class Sum (var a: Int,var b: Int){

    fun add(): Int= a + b //you can return the results directly.
}
```

you can test your code using the main below.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   var s= Sum(1,2)

    print(s.add())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because

- Kotlin dont have support if you declare and even initialize 2 field variables on same line
- There is default setter and getter associated with each field variable in kotlin

so when you declared them on same line, the first variable initialized with default setters and getters but the other one expects that you will give your own setter and getter because syntax was wrong

Error can be resolved via 2 ways

- Declare setter and getter separately like this

  ```
  var a:Int
    get() {
       return 0
    }
    set(value) {
        val b = value
    }
  ```
- Correct the syntax

  ```
   var a: Int
   var b: Int
  ```