# Meaning of comma in Kotlin in member variables

Tags: kotlin

I came across this line of code in Kotlin:

```
private val creators: ArrayMap<Class<*>,() ->ViewModel> = ArrayMap()
```

What does the comma mean? Is this a bug? According to this post, commas are not allowed:

[Define multiple variables at once in Kotlin (e.g Java : String x,y,z;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385878/define-multiple-variables-at-once-in-kotlin-e-g-java-string-x-y-z)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma separates the generic parameters of `ArrayMap`. The first parameter is `Class<*>`, while the second parameter is `() -> ViewModel`