# How to prevent formatter from adding line break after semicolon?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm developing a class with JavaFX properties and using the tornadoFX library in order to create property delegates for each.

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty
import tornadofx.getValue
import tornadofx.setValue

typealias SLP = SimpleLongProperty

class MyClass {

    val totalSpaceP = SLP(0); var totalSpace by totalSpaceP
    val usableSpaceP = SLP(0); var usableSpace by usableSpaceP
    val freeSpaceP = SLP(0); var freeSpace by freeSpaceP

}
```

The above compiles, but upon autoformating in IntelliJ, I get this:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty
import tornadofx.getValue
import tornadofx.setValue

typealias SLP = SimpleLongProperty

class MyClass {

    val totalSpaceP = SLP(0);
    var totalSpace by totalSpaceP
    val usableSpaceP = SLP(0);
    var usableSpace by usableSpaceP
    val freeSpaceP = SLP(0);
    var freeSpace by freeSpaceP

}
```

I understand [declaring multiple properties on one line is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036345/how-to-declare-several-properties-on-one-line). However, semicolons allow a workaround. I understand this is not conventional. However, this is more legible to me and I am the sole developer.

Am I missing a setting in IntelliJ that disables the adding of line breaks after semicolons during autoformatting? Is there another workaround I have not thought of?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that readability is key, however, both don't look particularly great. Since you're not really saving any resources by condensing code, maybe you could try:

```
class MyClass {

    val totalSpaceP = SLP(0)
    var totalSpace by totalSpaceP

    val usableSpaceP = SLP(0)
    var usableSpace by usableSpaceP

    val freeSpaceP = SLP(0)
    var freeSpace by freeSpaceP

}
```

This way, all your properties and variables aren't bunched up, and you're not trying to force one-liners.